# spring-security-saml2-sample not working

Tags: spring

I am trying to run the application provided at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml(master version) and chosen  option http://idp.ssocircle.com and clicked start single-sign on button, then clicked continue saml-single-sign-on, then it took me to error page and I am getting error as below
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/spring-security-saml2-sample3] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException

```
at org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPAOS11Binding.supports(HTTPPAOS11Binding.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl.getBinding(SAMLProcessorImpl.java:260)
at org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl.retrieveMessage(SAMLProcessorImpl.java:172)
at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:80)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:195)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
```

- SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
- SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed

Comment: I have downloaded code from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml.git

Answer (score 0):

after struggling for few days, finally I was able to resolve the issue.  I am sorry to say that I have not received any single reply from this forum.

Comment: Now that you've got an answer to this, please update the solution instead!

Comment: I have adjusted the time so that idp and sp are in synch and changed the jar files in java> jre>security> added unlimited JCE files here